IF Status Formula Google Sheet Approval
I need to know the status of my ticket approval..
=IF(A2="","",IF(B2<>"","FOR 2ND APPROVAL",IF(C2<>"","FOR 3RD APPROVAL",IF(D2<>"","FOR 4TH APPROVAL",IF(E2<>"","FOR 5TH APPROVAL",IF(A2<>"","FOR 1ST APPROVAL",""))))))
The status is not updating. Here is the sample I need in my sheet.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1x3Upa0qhTItyVjXiNwTaIsbajq4ac4cZsX7Pap27KGE/edit?gid=0#gid=0

Consider providing input and expected output as plain text table in the question. Click here to create a table easily, which are easy to copy/paste.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question useless for others or images, which are hard to copy. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.

You may try the following formula-
=IF(A2="",,XLOOKUP(0,INDEX(--B2:F2),$B$1:$F$1,"APPROVED"))

Dynamic spill formula-
=BYROW(B2:F,LAMBDA(r,IF(INDEX(A:A,ROW(r))="",,XLOOKUP(0,INDEX(--r),$B$1:$F$1,"APPROVED"))))



Hi @Harun24hr. How can I add the word "FOR" in the status?

@RhenzIdolIiSanPedro Try =IF(A2="",,INDEX(XLOOKUP(0,--B2:F2,"FOR "& $B$1:$F$1,"APPROVED"))).

that works. Thank you
